# How do I check what version of syslinux I have?

Tags: linux, centos, syslinux

How do I check what version of syslinux I have?

Comment: Is there an RPM independent way of determining the version say if one installed it from source?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We installed from sources,

```
$ strings syslinux | grep SYSLINUX
SYSLINUX
SYSLINUX 3.72 2008-09-25
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with

```
rpm -qf $(type -p syslinux)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using CentOS, you can see what version of the RPM you have installed.

```
[user@host ~]$ which syslinux
/usr/bin/syslinux
[user@host ~]$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/syslinux
syslinux-3.11-4
```

Comment: Or even: $ rpm -qf `which syslinux`

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, try `dpkg -s syslinux`